# tkinter, creating frames with button and delay

Tags: python, tkinter, frame

so i am trying to create multiple frames with a button but with delays between them, so i press the button --> create frame1 --> wait 5 second --> create frame2 and so on. But the problem is that when i press the button it takes 5 seconds and displays the frame's at the same time. hopefully someone has any idea how to solve this.

```
import tkinter as tk
import time

class lingo(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.grid_rowconfigure(0,minsize=1080)
        self.grid_columnconfigure(0,minsize=1810)

        m = tk.Frame(self)
        m.grid(row=0, column=0,sticky="nsew")

        h1 = tk.Frame(m)
        h1.grid(row=0, column=0)
        e1 = tk.Entry(h1)
        e1.grid(row=0, column=0)
        def get_entry():
            entry1 = e1.get()
            print(entry1)
            print(list(entry1))
            def test1():
                r1l1t = tk.Label(r1l1, text=a1, font=("",40), fg="white")
                r1l1t.grid()
                r1l1t['bg'] = r1l1['bg']

                r1l2t = tk.Label(r1l2, text=a2, font=("",40), fg="white")
                r1l2t.grid()
                r1l2t['bg'] = r1l2['bg']


            if len(entry1) < 19:
                print("te kort woord")
            if len(entry1) > 19:
                print("te lang woord")
            if len(entry1) == 19:
                a1, a2, a3, a4, a5, a6, a7, a8, a9, a10, a11, a12, a13, a14, a15, a16, a17, a18, a19 = list(entry1)
                test1()


        m.grid_rowconfigure(0, minsize=100)
        m.grid_rowconfigure(1, minsize=100)
        m.grid_columnconfigure(0, minsize=1810)
        b1 = tk.Button(h1, bg="blue", text="enter", command=get_entry)
        b1.grid(row=0, column=1)

        row1 = tk.Frame(m, bg="grey")
        row1.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky="nsew")

        for c in range(0, 38):
            if c % 2 == 0:
                row1.grid_columnconfigure(c, minsize=5)
            else:
                row1.grid_columnconfigure(c, minsize=90)

        row1.grid_rowconfigure(0, minsize=5)
        row1.grid_rowconfigure(1, minsize=90)
        row1.grid_rowconfigure(2, minsize=5)



        r1l1 = tk.Frame(row1, bg="blue")
        r1l1.grid(row=1, column=1, sticky="nsew")
        r1l1.grid_rowconfigure(0, minsize=90)
        r1l1.grid_columnconfigure(0, minsize=90)

        # r1l1t = tk.Label(r1l1, text=".....", font=("",40), fg="white")
        # r1l1t.grid()
        # r1l1t['bg'] = r1l1['bg']


        r1l2 = tk.Frame(row1, bg="blue")
        r1l2.grid(row=1, column=3, sticky="nsew")
        r1l2.grid_rowconfigure(0, minsize=90)
        r1l2.grid_columnconfigure(0, minsize=90)

        # r1l2t = tk.Label(r1l2, text=".....", font=("",40), fg="white")
        # r1l2t.grid()
        # r1l2t['bg'] = r1l2['bg']


        r1l3 = tk.Frame(row1, bg="blue")
        r1l3.grid(row=1, column=5, sticky="nsew")
        r1l3.grid_rowconfigure(0, minsize=90)
        r1l3.grid_columnconfigure(0, minsize=90)

        r1l3t = tk.Label(r1l3, text=".....", font=("",40), fg="white")
        r1l3t.grid()
        r1l3t['bg'] = r1l3['bg']


        r1l4 = tk.Frame(row1, bg="blue")
        r1l4.grid(row=1, column=7, sticky="nsew")
        r1l4.grid_rowconfigure(0, minsize=90)
        r1l4.grid_columnconfigure(0, minsize=90)

        r1l4t = tk.Label(r1l4, text=".....", font=("",40), fg="white")
        r1l4t.grid()
        r1l4t['bg'] = r1l4['bg']


        r1l5 = tk.Frame(row1, bg="blue")
        r1l5.grid(row=1, column=9, sticky="nsew")
        r1l5.grid_rowconfigure(0, minsize=90)
        r1l5.grid_columnconfigure(0, minsize=90)

        r1l5t = tk.Label(r1l5, text=".....", font=("",40), fg="white")
        r1l5t.grid()
        r1l5t['bg'] = r1l5['bg']


        r1l6 = tk.Frame(row1, bg="blue")
        r1l6.grid(row=1, column=11, sticky="nsew")
        r1l6.grid_rowconfigure(0, minsize=90)
        r1l6.grid_columnconfigure(0, minsize=90)

        r1l6t = tk.Label(r1l6, text=".....", font=("",40), fg="white")
        r1l6t.grid()
        r1l6t['bg'] = r1l6['bg']


        r1l7 = tk.Frame(row1, bg="blue")
        r1l7.grid(row=1, column=13, sticky="nsew")
        r1l7.grid_rowconfigure(0, minsize=90)
        r1l7.grid_columnconfigure(0, minsize=90)

        r1l7t = tk.Label(r1l7, text=".....", font=("",40), fg="white")
        r1l7t.grid()
        r1l7t['bg'] = r1l7['bg']


        r1l8 = tk.Frame(row1, bg="blue")
        r1l8.grid(row=1, column=15, sticky="nsew")
        r1l8.grid_rowconfigure(0, minsize=90)
        r1l8.grid_columnconfigure(0, minsize=90)

        r1l8t = tk.Label(r1l8, text=".....", font=("",40), fg="white")
        r1l8t.grid()
        r1l8t['bg'] = r1l8['bg']


        r1l9 = tk.Frame(row1, bg="blue")
        r1l9.grid(row=1, column=17, sticky="nsew")
        r1l9.grid_rowconfigure(0, minsize=90)
        r1l9.grid_columnconfigure(0, minsize=90)

        r1l9t = tk.Label(r1l9, text=".....", font=("",40), fg="white")
        r1l9t.grid()
        r1l9t['bg'] = r1l9['bg']     


        r1l10 = tk.Frame(row1, bg="blue")
        r1l10.grid(row=1, column=19, sticky="nsew")
        r1l10.grid_rowconfigure(0, minsize=90)
        r1l10.grid_columnconfigure(0, minsize=90)

        r1l10t = tk.Label(r1l10, text=".....", font=("",40), fg="white")
        r1l10t.grid()
        r1l10t['bg'] = r1l10['bg']


        r1l11 = tk.Frame(row1, bg="blue")
        r1l11.grid(row=1, column=21, sticky="nsew")
        r1l11.grid_rowconfigure(0, minsize=90)
        r1l11.grid_columnconfigure(0, minsize=90)

        r1l11t = tk.Label(r1l11, text=".....", font=("",40), fg="white")
        r1l11t.grid()
        r1l11t['bg'] = r1l11['bg']


        r1l12 = tk.Frame(row1, bg="blue")
        r1l12.grid(row=1, column=23, sticky="nsew")
        r1l12.grid_rowconfigure(0, minsize=90)
        r1l12.grid_columnconfigure(0, minsize=90)

        r1l12t = tk.Label(r1l12, text=".....", font=("",40), fg="white")
        r1l12t.grid()
        r1l12t['bg'] = r1l12['bg']


        r1l13 = tk.Frame(row1, bg="blue")
        r1l13.grid(row=1, column=25, sticky="nsew")
        r1l13.grid_rowconfigure(0, minsize=90)
        r1l13.grid_columnconfigure(0, minsize=90)

        r1l13t = tk.Label(r1l13, text=".....", font=("",40), fg="white")
        r1l13t.grid()
        r1l13t['bg'] = r1l13['bg']


        r1l14 = tk.Frame(row1, bg="blue")
        r1l14.grid(row=1, column=27, sticky="nsew")
        r1l14.grid_rowconfigure(0, minsize=90)
        r1l14.grid_columnconfigure(0, minsize=90)

        r1l14t = tk.Label(r1l14, text=".....", font=("",40), fg="white")
        r1l14t.grid()
        r1l14t['bg'] = r1l14['bg']

        r1l15 = tk.Frame(row1, bg="blue")
        r1l15.grid(row=1, column=29, sticky="nsew")
        r1l15.grid_rowconfigure(0, minsize=90)
        r1l15.grid_columnconfigure(0, minsize=90)

        r1l15t = tk.Label(r1l15, text=".....", font=("",40), fg="white")
        r1l15t.grid()
        r1l15t['bg'] = r1l15['bg']

        r1l16 = tk.Frame(row1, bg="blue")
        r1l16.grid(row=1, column=31, sticky="nsew")
        r1l16.grid_rowconfigure(0, minsize=90)
        r1l16.grid_columnconfigure(0, minsize=90)

        r1l16t = tk.Label(r1l16, text=".....", font=("",40), fg="white")
        r1l16t.grid()
        r1l16t['bg'] = r1l16['bg']

        r1l17 = tk.Frame(row1, bg="blue")
        r1l17.grid(row=1, column=33, sticky="nsew")
        r1l17.grid_rowconfigure(0, minsize=90)
        r1l17.grid_columnconfigure(0, minsize=90)

        r1l17t = tk.Label(r1l17, text=".....", font=("",40), fg="white")
        r1l17t.grid()
        r1l17t['bg'] = r1l17['bg']


        r1l18 = tk.Frame(row1, bg="blue")
        r1l18.grid(row=1, column=35, sticky="nsew")
        r1l18.grid_rowconfigure(0, minsize=90)
        r1l18.grid_columnconfigure(0, minsize=90)

        r1l18t = tk.Label(r1l18, text=".....", font=("",40), fg="white")
        r1l18t.grid()
        r1l18t['bg'] = r1l18['bg']

        r1l19 = tk.Frame(row1, bg="blue")
        r1l19.grid(row=1, column=37, sticky="nsew")
        r1l19.grid_rowconfigure(0, minsize=90)
        r1l19.grid_columnconfigure(0, minsize=90)

        r1l19t = tk.Label(r1l19, text=".....", font=("",40), fg="white")
        r1l19t.grid()
        r1l19t['bg'] = r1l19['bg']

app = lingo()
app.wm_geometry("1810x1080")
app.resizable(False, False)
app.title("pls work")
app.mainloop()
```

so i added the whole code this time, and tried to replace r1l2t.grid() with r1l2t.after(1000, r1l2t.grid()) but with no change....

Comment: Actually it is not enough. I think something `r1l1.update_idletasks()` might help you but without a [mcve] it is just a long shot..

Comment: It is usually not recommended to use `time.sleep` along  with tkinter because it suspends tkinter's mainloop and therefore freezes the GUI. To execute a command with a delay, you can use the [`after` command](http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/universal.html) provided by tkinter instead.

Comment: @Goyo i tried it to use update_idletask but with no luck, and i added the whole code

Comment: @j_4321 what do you mean by time.sleep suspends tkinter? and how should is use the after command in my code? because r1l2t.after(1000, r1l2t.grid()) doesn't change anything :(

Comment: It is better you you make tour [mcve] actually minimal.

Comment: @Goyo O i see, sorry for that, i will edit the question in a few hours

Answer (score 0):

Once you have launched Tkinter's mainloop, the GUI waits for events (keystrokes, mouse clicks, ...) and reacts immediately when one occurs (visual effects on the clicked button, ...). However, when you use `time.sleep(5)`, you freeze this mainloop, so the GUI does not react when events occur but process them all after the end of the 5 seconds. In addition, the GUI does not update before the freezing so your first frame is displayed only at the end. You can force the GUI to update with the `update_idletasks()` method.

Tkinter provides a method to execute commands with a delay without freezing the mainloop: `app.after(delay , function, *args)` will execute `function(*args)` after the given delay (in ms). The mistake you made is that you called `r1l2t.after(1000, r1l2t.grid())` instead of `r1l2t.after(1000, r1l2t.grid)`. Below is a small example creating two labels on a button press with a 5s delay between each:

```
import tkinter as tk

app = tk.Tk()

def display():
    l1 = tk.Label(app, text='First label')
    l2 = tk.Label(app, text='Second label')
    l1.grid()
    app.after(5000, l2.grid)

tk.Button(app, text='Display', command=display).grid()


app.mainloop()
```